# find the last occurrence of a word in a sentence using regular expression

Tags: regex

I am trying to get the value 13941 using regular expression but with no luck. any help would be appreciated.

```
 VALUES('0','test',1,'58','13941',
```

output should be: 13941

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\b\d+\b(?=\D*$)
```

This should do it for you.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/iS6jF6/15

Comment: i will in 10 mins because i cant now. can you please explain briefly what is the ?=